# NSSecureCoding crash in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsvalue, nsvaluetransformer, nssecurecoding

I am getting crash reports from users when fetching from my Core Data entity with a fetch request. This is what the crash looks like:

> SIGABRT: Unhandled error (NSCocoaErrorDomain, 4864) occurred during
> faulting and was thrown: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864
> "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2822582d0 {Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'NS.objects' was of
> unexpected class 'NSTextAlternatives (0x1ffa90890)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]'. Allowed
> classes are '{( "NSTextAttachment (0x1ff3bc730)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSNumber
> (0x1ff35d8c8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
> "NSDictionary (0x1ff352418)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "NSFont
> (0x1ff3bc3e8)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]",
> "NSGlyphInfo (0x1ffa906d8)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSArray
> (0x1ff352238) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
> "NSParagraphStyle (0x1ff3bbec0)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSUUID
> (0x1ff35f290) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
> "NSDate (0x1ff3522b0)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "NSColor
> (0x1ff3a67a8)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework]", "NSNull
> (0x1ff3527b0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
> "NSData (0x1ff3519c8)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "UIColor
> (0x1ff3a6a78)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework]",
> "NSAttributedString (0x1ff359c00)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]", "NSURL
> (0x1ff352e18) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
> "NSSet (0x1ff352878)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "NSValue
> (0x1ff35d940) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
> "UIFont (0x1ff3bc780)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSString
> (0x1ff35d170) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]" )}'."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'NS.objects' was of
> unexpected class 'NSTextAlternatives (0x1ffa90890)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]'. Allowed
> classes are '{( "NSTextAttachment (0x1ff3bc730)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSNumber
> (0x1ff35d8c8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
> "NSDictionary (0x1ff352418)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "NSFont
> (0x1ff3bc3e8)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]",
> "NSGlyphInfo (0x1ffa906d8)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSArray
> (0x1ff352238) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
> "NSParagraphStyle (0x1ff3bbec0)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSUUID
> (0x1ff35f290) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
> "NSDate (0x1ff3522b0)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "NSColor
> (0x1ff3a67a8)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework]", "NSNull
> (0x1ff3527b0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
> "NSData (0x1ff3519c8)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "UIColor
> (0x1ff3a6a78)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework]",
> "NSAttributedString (0x1ff359c00)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]", "NSURL
> (0x1ff352e18) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
> "NSSet (0x1ff352878)
> [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]", "NSValue
> (0x1ff35d940) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
> "UIFont (0x1ff3bc780)
> [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework]", "NSString
> (0x1ff35d170) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]"
> )}'.}}}CrashVersion 5.6.8 (5.6.9)1 user1 report

The line it crashes at is when `NSFetchedResultsController` is calling `performFetch`:

> 7   CoreData                             0x00000001b48c1a94
> __43-[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]_block_invoke + 572 8   CoreData                             0x00000001b487c01c
> developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 152 9
> CoreData                             0x00000001b474eda4
> -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 204 10  CoreData                             0x00000001b475cae4 -[NSFetchedResultsController
> _recursivePerformBlockAndWait:withContext:] + 144 11  CoreData                             0x00000001b475cc1c -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:] + 220

This is almost certainly happening because I recently changed a Transformable attribute which didn't have any transformer set (so essentially using `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName`) to using a subclass of `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`. The attribute is storing an `NSAttributedString` that comes from a `UITextView` in an iOS app. And I also save the NSRange for the 'bold' and 'italics' items as an NSValue.

I added the following transformer:

```
@objc(AttributedStringDictionaryTransformer)
final class AttributedStringDictionaryTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {

    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return super.allowedTopLevelClasses + [NSValue.self]
    }
}
```

This 'transformer' is used in the Transformable attributed in the Core Data model. It adds the `NSValue` class to the allowed list of classes.

When it says "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSTextAlternatives " ... I'm not sure what `NSTextAlternatives` is. I have never (explicitly) used this in my code. Any ideas where it might be coming from?

EDIT:
On further investigation, it turns out NSAttributedString can tack on all sorts of objects, like objects for `NSTextAlternatives` and `_UITextInputDictationResultMetadata`, which might be present if the user uses dictation on the UITextView. So the `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`, which technically supports NSAttributedString, doesn't actually support it properly. These classes are coming from private frameworks, so not sure how I can add them to my custom transformer. Not sure there is a work-around other than filing a bug. If there is, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `NSAttributedString` can be a bit of a grab-bag of text-system-related attributes: various operations in text views can cause the text system (CoreText, UIKit, etc.) to annotate ranges with bits of metadata to improve the iOS experience, but it does mean that any given `NSAttributedString` can end up with bits of baggage you might not be aware of. (Conceptually, `NSAttributedString` is like an `NSString` with an associated `NSDictionary` which can contain *anything*, if you squint just right.) Regular usage of text views can cause this, and when you factor in pasting text from *other* attributed string sources, too, you can end up with many attribute values you don't expect. This is the text system working as expected.

Unfortunately, this design butts heads with `NSSecureCoding`, which requires you to list out the types that you expect to decode from an archive before decoding it. You're correctly whitelisting `NSAttributedString` and `NSValue` objects, and `NSAttributedString` itself whitelists several types that it is aware of (and `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` also allows some known Foundation types), but the issue is that the string ultimately contains types that *neither* you *nor* `NSAttributedString` know about, and without whitelisting those, decoding will be prevented.

Since these types are indeed private, you're going to have a rough time trying to find all possible private types the text system can throw at you. The easiest way forward would be on the *encoding* side: before you encode an `NSAttributedString`, iterate over all of its attribute ranges and strip out any attributes whose types don't meet your whitelisting criteria. Using the same criteria at encode time that you use at decode time will allow you to decode successfully.

Comment: This is for an existing app in production, which already saves the attributedText from a UITextView directly. The temporary solution I guess is to go back to using `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` for now, and then later on, do some processing to strip out all these private attributes from `NSAttributedString` before using `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`.

Comment: @ZS Yep, you'll need a migration strategy for the data. You may need a build (or a few) which continues to use the non-secure transformer, but migrates the data forward by stripping the attributes and re-saving. Or, if the saved data is versioned in any way, you can migrate old data versions forward on load. The main concerns would be interop between old and new versions of the app (if applicable).